# Hit fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I programming a simple game and at the first collision I get the following error:

> Hit fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)

Here's my code:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
    var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB

    } else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }

    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.Monster != 0) &&
        (secondBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.naboj != 0)) {
            projectileDidCollideWithMonster(firstBody.node as SKSpriteNode, monster: secondBody.node as SKSpriteNode)

    }

}
```

Comment: Which row is it crashing on?

Comment: projectileDidCollideWithMonster(firstBody.node as SKSpriteNode, monster: secondBody.node as SKSpriteNode)

Comment: I would guess firstBody or node then can be nil. If you breakpoint on this row, what values does firstBody.node and secondBody.node have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using swift 1 or 1.2?

Try

```
if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.Monster != 0) &&
    (secondBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.naboj != 0)) {

    if let firstNode = firstBody.node as? SKSprintNode,
       let secondNode = secondBody.node as? SKSprinteNode {

       projectileDidCollideWithMonster(firstNode, monster: secondNode)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem before, this is what I did

Basically, when you're unwrapping the physics body (this usually happens at the line that says `secondBody.node!`) the following happens:

1. If you have 3 bodies (`a`, `b`, `c`) that collide, and collision logic applies to all 3, sprite kit will perform 2 collision checks:

   - One with bodies `a` and `b`
   - then with bodies `b` and `c`
2. you are removing bodies on collision:

   - **first detection :** bodies `a` and `b` are unwrapped, bodies `a` and `b` are removed
   - **second detection :** only body `c` is left because `a` and `b` were removed. This means `secondBody` or `firstBody` is now nil. So the error is thrown

Try changing your code to the following, and it should fix the issue:

```
var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody?
var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody?

if (firstBody!.node! != nil && secondBody!.node! != nil) {
       if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.Monster != 0) &&
                (secondBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.Projectile != 0)) {
                projectileDidCollideWithMonster(secondBody.node!, monster: firstBody.node!)
        }
}
```

Comment: `if (firstBody!.node! != nil && secondBody!.node! != nil)` will crash if any of these force unwrapped values are nil... Better use `if let` (or nil coalescing) to test if the objects exist.

Comment: This is a good explanation for what happens. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.Monster != 0) &&
    (secondBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.naboj != 0)) {
    if(firstBody.node != nil && secondBody.node != nil ) {
        projectileDidCollideWithMonster(firstBody.node as SKSpriteNode, monster: secondBody.node as SKSpriteNode) }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok this took me a while to figure out but I got it in the end. I tried most of the other solutions I could find online with very little luck. I had to figure it out the hard way. What you have to do is give the option of a break/ return if a nil is found. Because most of the time this error occurs when two of the same collisions are triggered simultaneously.

what I did is make a if else statement to return the function if a nil occurs.

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody

if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
    firstBody = contact.bodyA
    secondBody = contact.bodyB

} else {
    firstBody = contact.bodyB
    secondBody = contact.bodyA
}

if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.Monster != 0) &&
    (secondBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.naboj != 0)) {
// new part
    if (firstBody.node == nil || secondBody.node == nil)
    {return}

else {
 projectileDidCollideWithMonster(firstBody.node as SKSpriteNode, monster: secondBody.node as SKSpriteNode)
}}}
```

I hope this helps. 
It is also important that you treat it like you are expecting a nil by having the return statement in the if and not the else.